# How to execute script file before another script in layout page?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-core, layout

Inside my layout page i wanna run a script for translate the text of some enumumerators.

My layout looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
         <script src="~/js/ViewModels/Helpers/Translation.js"></script>
         <script src="~/js/ViewModels/Helpers/Enumerators.js"></script>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
       ...
    </body>
</html>
```

My translation script:

```
'use strict';

var jsonTranstation = null;
$(function () {
    getjson();
});

const getjson = () => {    
    $.getJSON('/lib/translation/en-EN.json', function (data) {
        jsonTranstation = data;
    });

}

const Translation = (value, ViewModel) => {
    let a = null;
    if (jsonTranstation ) {
        a = jsonTranstation[ViewModel][value];
        return a;
    }
    return '--';
}
```

My Enumerators script:

```
'use strict'

const EnumToolBar = {
    NEW: { text: Translation('New', 'EnumToolBar'), prefixIcon: 'e-add', id: 'NEW' }
}
```

My JSON file (en-EN.json):

```
{
  "EnumToolBar": {
    "New": "New Value"
  }
}
```

Using EnumToolBar.NEW.text in HomePage returns '--' instead of 'New Value'.
There are any way to read first script and the respective json file before any other script?

Comment: As we all known, if we aren't dynamically loading scripts or marking them as `defer` or `async`, then scripts are loaded in the order encountered in the page. So, by using your code it will first load the Translation.js, then Enumerators.js. I have created a sample using your code, the EnumToolBar.NEW.text value is `--`, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf3tS.png). If still not working, try to clear the browser data frist, then, you could consider use [the `defer` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp).

Comment: Just changed the function getjson to this and worked -> $.ajax({
    url: '/lib/traducoes/en-EN.json',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        jsonTranstation= response;
    }
});